# 'Connection refused to host' al intentar usar un RemoteEngine/Load generator en Jenkins(+JMeter)

Tags: linux, docker, jenkins, jmeter

estoy intentando realizar un sistema esclavo-maestro, en donde desde Jenkins levanto un script de JMeter para que sea corrido desde diferentes dispositivos al mismo tiempo.
El problema viene al intentar establecer una conexión con el esclavo, me tira error de connection refused siendo que yo desde el cmd tiro un ping a esa dirección ip y los paquetes van y vienen sin problemas. Ponga la ip que ponga, incluso la mia, tira error. Adjunto el mensaje de consola de Jenkins;

```
 + /var/jenkins_home/apache-jmeter-5.4.1/bin/jmeter.sh -n -t /var/jenkins_home/workspace/JMeterTest/JMeter_Script_Plugins.jmx -l /var/jenkins_home/workspace/JMeterTest/JMeter_Script_Plugins-27.jtl -Jthreads=10 -Jrampup=10 -Jduration=10 -R XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX(IP) -e -o /var/jenkins_home/workspace/JMeterTest/27
Creating summariser <summary>
Created the tree successfully using /var/jenkins_home/workspace/JMeterTest/JMeter_Script_Plugins.jmx
Configuring remote engine: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX(IP)
Connection refused to host: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX(IP); nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
Failed to configure XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX(IP)
Stopping remote engines
Remote engines have been stopped
Error in NonGUIDriver java.lang.RuntimeException: Following remote engines could not be configured:[XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX(IP)]
An error occurred: Error in NonGUIDriver Following remote engines could not be configured:[XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX(IP)]
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: El host/puerto al que la aplicación se está tratando de conectar está disponible? Una forma sencilla de saberlo es, desde ese mismo servidor, trata de conectarte con telnet: `telnet el-host el-puerto`. Si no se conecta (creo que es lo que va a suceder) entonces tienes que ir a mirar si el puerto está abierto en el _otro_ equipo o si el tráfico está siendo filtrado.

Comment: Por cierto... puedes ir agregando el resultado de las pruebas (por ejemplo el telnet) en la pregunta para continuar con el análisis.

Comment: Ahi intenté hacer lo que me dijiste con la ip de un compañero de trabajo(a la cual puedo acceder mediante un ping) y se queda en loop en 'trying xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx(ip)' Tendrás idea de como ver lo de si los puertos están abiertos o lo del tráfico filtrado? La verdad que de redes tengo poca idea, y encima estoy trabajando en linux que también es nuevo para mi. Gracias por tu respuesta

Comment: Podrías colocar el comando telnet que usaste en la pregunta y su salida?

Comment: Utilicé el comando telnet ip puerto y se queda en 'Trying ip puerto' en loop, hasta que yo corte manualmente la ejecucion. Estoy siguiendo esta guía para realizar el funcionamiento, por si te sirve para algo. https://jmeterenespanol.org/blog/2020-08-21-jenkins-github-antonio/

Comment: por favor, pon el telnet y su salida como parte de la pregunta para que las personas que entren y vean la pregunta no tengan que hacer el recorrido por los comentarios.